# ModalPopupExtender doesn't show on some computers

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I maintain a vb.net website. A button on a page shows an AjaxControlToolkit.dll ModalPopupExtender. When I click the button, the page reloads, but no popup appears.

My tests below cover the scenarios I can think of. Please help me diagnose and fix.

- This ModalPopupExtender succeeded in the past. The error might have started when we moved to a new server, or when we implemented https, or a browser update, or at some other time since then.
- Tried Chrome (latest) and Firefox.
- I RDPed into the server and opened the page in Chrome there. ModalPopupExtender succeeded. Same Chrome version as my PC. So, unlikely to be a code issue.
- A different page on the same site uses ModalPopupExtender successfully. So, unlikely to be local PC settings.
- I put lines of test code immediately before and after ModalPopupExtender.Show(). Both succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha - found it!

**Solution**

The ASPX/HTML referred to **http**://ajax.googleapis.com. Changing the references to **https** made ModalPopupExtender.Show() work correctly for me.

**Explanation/Diagnosis** (if you can clarify further, please comment)

When I checked the html served to my browser, I noticed it defined a javascript function called fn(). The definition for fn() didn't appear in the html served to the server's browser. After the https change, fn() no longer appears in the html I receive. The other page, where ModalPopupExtender worked, didn't have any reference to googleapis.com.

I assume that using http instead of https caused ajax.googleapis.com to provide fn() and that fn() in some way interfered with the normal operation of my ModalPopupExtender.

Here's the fn() definition: `(function {var fn = function() {Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior.invokeViaServer('ctl00_cphContent_ModalPopupExtenderConfirm', true); Sys.Application.remove_load(fn);};Sys.Application.add_load(fn);})();`

Note: the http also included another javascript function related to the ModalPopupExtender. But there was a similar one on the working page, and in the working version served to the server's browser, and in my fixed version. So, I assume that function is correct.